# How to detect if the phone app is available for various devices using iphone os

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

I'd like to show or hide a button that lets a user make a phone call based on whether or not the user can actually make a call (iPhone or iPod touch).  Is it possible to somehow detect if the phone app is available to the user in cocoa-touch?  Or am i constrained to detecting the device type to make that distinction?  I would rather check for functionality than static clients in case something changes down the line for whatever reason (not that iPod touch users could ever make non-voip phone calls anyways, but the code would be cleaner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BOOL canMakePhoneCalls = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                           canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:5555555"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try it out as soon as i can!

Comment: I like this solution in particular because it allows a user to install some other app to support tel:// on a device missing hardware phone.