# How to find out whether the iPhone / iPod Phone can be used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipod-touch

what is the best way to find out whether the current device supports a **phone call**?

iPod Touch does not support it at all and iPhone does only support calls after entering the SIM password.

Is there a similar method like `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` for mail?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395224/how-to-detect-if-the-phone-app-is-available-for-various-devices-using-iphone-os

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395224/how-to-detect-if-the-phone-app-is-available-for-various-devices-using-iphone-os), and the answer is this:

```
BOOL canCall = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                       canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1234567"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I forget exactly how, but I believe there's a way to check if the device responds to the `tel:` URL handler.

Comment: Okay, Kevlar's answer is exactly what I was thinking of.